# How to access read-only Derby databases over a network client connection?

Tags: derby, readonly

I'm trying to open a read-only Derby database over a network client connection (using ij / derbyclient.jar).

I have created a read-only database:

```
jar cMf sample.jar sample
```

The Derby Network Server is started.

I have tried the following connection URLs:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:jar://localhost:1527/sample.jar';
connect 'jdbc:derby:jar://localhost:1527/(sample.jar)sample';
connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/jar:(sample.jar)sample';
```

But none of the above URLs work.

The only URL that works is:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:jar:(sample.jar)sample';
```

It appears that read-only Derby databases can only be opened in embedded mode. Is this true ?

**Solved:**

After checking the "derby.log", the problem was that the read-only database needs to be able to create a temporary file.

derby.log:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'jar:(sample.jar)sample' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d450337, see the next exception for details.
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'jar:(sample.jar)sample' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d450337, see the next exception for details.
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: 'Unable to create temporary file: java.lang.SecurityException'.
...
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file
```

The solution is to define a temporary directory for the database. This can be done with the "derby.storage.tempDirectory" property:

- System-wide in "derby.properties":

  ```
  derby.storage.tempDirectory=c:/temp
  ```
- Database-wide

  ```
  CallableStatement cs = 
      conn.prepareCall("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(?, ?)"); 
  cs.setString(1, "derby.storage.tempDirectory"); 
  cs.setString(2, "c:/temp"); 
  cs.execute(); 
  cs.close();
  ```

The network URL is:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/jar:(sample.jar)sample';
```

Comment: You might try asking this question on the derby-user mailing list. I've only ever heard of jar-packaged databases being used in embedded applications, but that doesn't mean anything.